# Google oauth login in codenameone on android devices using native client not working

Tags: android, oauth, codenameone

I'm trying to implement GoogleConnect in a codenameone application. 
Everything works ok in the simulator, using the web client, however on the device the authentication process is delegated to the native login which keeps showing a pop-up to select a google account. Once I select an accout, the pop-up disappears briefly and it reappears. And the only way to make it get away is to close the app.

I tried to force GoogleConnect to use the web client but, surprise, Google is not allowing ouath loging from embedded user agents anymore, as they have announced in this post:

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

"In the coming months, we will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views".

I'm getting a "useragent_dissalowed" error.

So apparently the only solution to this is to fix the native login.

So coming back to this, it looks like the GoogleConnect instance that is used on my android device is GoogleImpl, and judging by the behaviour, it looks like it goes through the flow implemented in this code fragment:

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/social/GoogleImpl.java#L198-L209

I'm assuming that the "GoogleAuthUtil.getToken" is throwing an "UserRecoverableAuthException" and it keeps retrying, although this is not "recoverable" by any means. Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting the API level to 21 in the build hints and see if this works around that issue.

Comment: Tried setting android.targetSDKVersion=21 in the build hints, but I'm getting the same behaviour.

Comment: Was this something that worked in the past for you or is this the first time you are trying this?

Comment: First time. I have followed the steps described in the google login tutorial on codename one site. Set up the app on google developers site, created android credentials, provided sha-1 key and app main class package as required. Just as a side note, the facebook native login works, but google does not.

Answer (score 2):

I have just applied a patch that should fix this issue.  The fix will be available in the next server update (Friday).

[See patch here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/56a555138eea19d71e1af9b4054ddc5bf3b7f79e)

Comment: Thanks. I'll test this on friday. However, looking at the patch, instead of `RequestTokenTask task = new RequestTokenTask();  
 task.inRecoverableRequest = true;  
 task.extra = recover.getExtras();  
 task.execute();`   can't you just get and set the token directly from the extra, like so: `String token=recover.getExtras().getString("authtoken"); setAccessToken(new AccessToken(token, null));` ?

Comment: Yes you could do that too.

Comment: I have just tested this but I'm getting the same behaviour.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you please confirm that the patch reached the build servers. Maybe there's a different problem ?